# Blurry stripes on monitor

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card

I installed Windows 7 on my ideaPad G560 and there's a problem with the screen. There are vertical areas where the image is a little blurry that span across the screen's whole heigth. There are five or six such stripes. I'm using drivers from Windows Update. Other OSes installed on the coputer (Ubuntu, FreeBSD) don't have that problem. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you are not running the OS in the native resolution of the display.  As a result the image is stretched slightly and not all pixels will coincide with the actual physical pixels of the display.

Make sure you are running at the native resolution of 1366×768

Comment: Huh, you're right. But the resolution tops out at 1360x768.

Comment: Check the Lenovo site to see if they have drivers specific to that model?